# svn log analysis detecting branch merge points

Tags: svn, merge

I would like to know it is possible to identify branch to trunk (or vice verse) merge points by analyzing subversion logs? As far as I understood, svn merge operates on the local copy and when we commit the applied changes, it looks like a normal commit (probably with more number of files and an message identifying the merge) and the only way of identifying it is relying on the comments. Is there any automatic way of identifying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v1.5 Subversion tracks merges by adding additional metadata to revisions. It stores this metadata in the svn:mergeinfo property of each revision. You can read about this metadata and the commands to retrieve it in [this chapter of the svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo) and also [this one](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo).

Unfortunately these references do not completely solve your problem, but they will get you started in the right direction.